# How to connect QSFP+ transceiver with MPO connector and SFP+ transceiver with LC connector?

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, sfp

In data center application, 40G QSFP+ transceivers with MPO connector and 10G SFP+ transceivers with LC connectors are most common transceivers. But, with two different connectors, how can we make a connection between these transceivers? And how long the distance the network connection can possibly reach?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need a breakout cable - MPO to 8x LC. The reach of the cable depends on the PHY that is used, e.g. 400 m for 10GBASE-SR over OM4, or 10 km for 10GBASE-LR over OS2.

Make sure that the transceivers on each end support matching PHYs, that the QSFP+ port supports breakout in your scenario, and that you match the breakout/patch cable type to the fiber type.

Of course, you can alternatively use a DAC breakout - go directly from QSFP+ to 4x SFP+.

Product recommendations are off-topic here, I'm afraid.